# Eclipse is not launching

Tags: eclipse, jvm, launch

I'm trying to run eclipse, but I keep getting this error. Any clue?

[image]

Comment: How much RAM do you have in your computer? If you don't have 1GB of free RAM (too many big apps and files open at the same time), there will be problems.

Answer (score 1):

not much to go on, but I hope this is of help to you: http://troyworks.com/blog/2008/06/08/eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-1/

Answer (score 0):

On `eclipse.ini`, change `-Xmx2048m` to `-Xmx1024m` and `-Xms1024m` to `-Xms512m`

Then try once again.